# Laravel get data which has date set and which has date empty

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

[image]

In this table the column `start_at` and `end_at` columns are nullable.

And I want to fetch the rows which has `end_at` filled and `end_at` not filled.
And `end_at` should be greater than equal to todays date.

I.E: Don't fetch rows which has `end_at` date older than today.

My code sofar:

```
    $date = today()->format('Y-m-d');
    $informations  = Information::where('end_at', '>=', $date)->get();
```

What query should I use to check the condition on same column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```php
Information::where('end_at', '>=', $date)->orWhereNull('end_at')->get();
```